# Python: how to use a for loop to delete and convert the form of certain items in a dictionary when meeting a condition

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

```
d = {0: {0: {0: 0, 1: 0},
         1: {0: 0,
             2: np.array([ 0.02981036])}},
     9: {0: {0: 0, 1: 0},
         7: {0: 0,
             4: np.array([ 0.01502996]),
             9: 0},
         8: {0: 0,
             1: 0},
         9: {0: 0, 1: 0}}}
```

The dictionary is above, what I want to is delete the keys of which the value is 0, and convert the array form to float. The wanted output is:

```
d = {0: {1: {2: 0.02981036}}, 9: {7: {4: 0.01502996}}}
```

I tried to use a for loop to delete the "0" items, but always got `KeyError: 0`. I am a newbie of `python`, please help me on board. Thanks!!

Comment: Please show us the code that you got the `KeyError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive solution:

```
def func(d):
    new_d = {}                           # create a new dict
    if any(v != 0 for v in d.values()):  # evaluate items if any `v != 0`
        for k, v in d.items():
            if type(v) == dict:
                new_v = func(v)
                if new_v:                # do not create key if `func(v)` is an empty dict
                    new_d[k] = new_v
            elif v != 0:                 # convert other non-zero values to float
                new_d[k] = float(v)      # place try/except here if you expect non-int values
        return new_d

>>> func(d)
Out[]: {0: {1: {2: 0.02981036}}, 9: {7: {4: 0.01502996}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is `dict` or `dict` of `dict`. Using `json` may be a good idea. But here is a scratch version of solution.

Also, since you are trying to delete keys while iterating through the keys at various levels, you may run into `RuntimError` issue. For that purpose we will need to `deepcopy` the `dict` , iterate through original and delete from the copy.

**SourceCode**

```
import numpy as np
import copy

d = {0: {0: {0: 0, 1: 0},
         1: {0: 0,
             2: np.array([ 0.02981036])}},
     9: {0: {0: 0, 1: 0},
         7: {0: 0,
             4: np.array([ 0.01502996]),
             9: 0},
         8: {0: 0,
             1: 0},
         9: {0: 0, 1: 0}}}

d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
for k1,v1 in d.iteritems():    
    for k2,v2 in v1.iteritems():
        for k3,v3 in v2.iteritems():
            #print k1,k2,k3,v3
            if v3 == 0:
                d2[k1][k2].pop(k3)
            if type(v3) is np.ndarray:
                v3 = v3.tolist()
                d2[k1][k2][k3] = float(''.join(str(i) for i in v3))

        if len(d2[k1][k2]) == 0:
            d2[k1].pop(k2)

 >>> d2
{0: {1: {2: 0.02981036}}, 9: {7: {4: 0.01502996}}}
```

Comment: This works, but it's very expensive, you can replace these loops by recursion

Comment: Note that `dict.iteritems()` has been replaced by `dict.items()` in Python3.

Comment: I understand. There was no constraints on time/space complexity from OP. and I am using 2.7 hence `dict.iteritems`. Also as I mentioned this was scratch/lazy attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy

def clean(d):
    new = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v == 0:
            pass
        elif isinstance(v, numpy.ndarray):
            new_element = float(v[0])
            new[k] = new_element
        else:
            new_element = clean(v)

            if new_element != {}:
                new[k] = new_element

    return new
```

https://repl.it/MO9A/1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to remove all zeros which have value 0:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

d = {0: {0: {0: 0, 1: 0},
         1: {0: 0,
             2: np.array([ 0.02981036])}},
     9: {0: {0: 0, 1: 0},
         7: {0: 0,
             4: np.array([ 0.01502996]),
             9: 0},
         8: {0: 0,
             1: 0},
         9: {0: 0, 1: 0}}}

deep_copy=deepcopy(d)
for key,value in d.items():
    for key1,value1 in value.items():
        for key2,value2 in value1.items():
            if value2==0:
                del deep_copy[key][key1][key2]






new_deep_copy=deepcopy(deep_copy)
for key,value in deep_copy.items():
    for key1,value1 in value.items():
        for key2,value2 in value1.items():
            if isinstance(value2,np.ndarray):
                new_deep_copy[key][key1][key2]=float(value2)


        if value1=={}:
            del new_deep_copy[key][key1]


print(new_deep_copy)
```

output:

```
{0: {1: {2: 36.0}}, 9: {7: {4: 0.01502996}}}
```